# Use of html in textarea not working correct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

My cms is actievadmin and just installed tinymce for editing in the textarea. When i make changes (bold, paragraph tags ect) the page showing raw html. In the DB is stored with the html but is not rendering the html.

Does anyone know what this problem is?

Comment: Can you give an example of code and what is rendered? May be you need to play with <%= ... and <%==

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the output on your page to something like this:

`<%=raw @model.content %>`